# How to call run() that refreshes screen information infinite times until user closes app

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I'm working on an app that monitors different device stats. Basically I want the app to refresh the statistics every second and show it to the user. For example a simple battery monitor

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable{

public void run(){
   fillField(R.id.fieldVoltage, battery.getVolt());
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    run();
}
```

this code works fine but if I add the actual refreshing

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    while(true){
        run();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the logcat refreshing but the screen is empty including all buttons and text. I think its because the onResume function doesn't actually end.

What logic should I use to implement the refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed because `onResume()` never returns. There are two reasons for your problem:

- `while(true)`
- `Thread.sleep(1000)`

Both you should never do anytime. In your case these block your main thread.

Instead use a main thread [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to schedule the `Runnable` delayed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void run(){
        fillField(R.id.fieldVoltage, battery.getVolt());
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }

    [....]
}
```